# AS2 - hitTest function not working

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I've got the following code for a simple birds eye view platformer.
It moves but when the main movieclip collides with the background it doesnt change the speeds variable to 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
onClipEvent(load){
    var speeds:Number = 5;
}

onClipEvent(enterFrame){
    if(Key.isDown(37)){
        _root.back._x += speeds;
    }
    if(Key.isDown(39)){
        _root.back._x -= speeds;
    }
    if(Key.isDown(38)){
        _root.back._y += speeds;
    }
    if(Key.isDown(40)){
        _root.back._y -= speeds;
    }
    if(_root.mcMain.hitTest(_x, _y, true)){
        _root.speeds = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        _root.speeds = 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `_root.mcMain.hitTest("back")`?!
I dunno what is `back` or `mcMain` but the code I said can check `mcMain` and `back` collision!
I hope it helps